# on profile image use ternary operation using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am making project. In profile picture all the source taken from server. I have difficulty with **when profile picture is null then display default user image else display User's uploaded picture.**

I am trying :

```
<img ng-src="{{rec.ProfilePic=='null' ? '~/img/UserDefault.png' :'{{rec.ProfilePic'}}"
     class="img-thumbnail img-fluid"
     style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:20px"
     alt="profile photo" />
```

After that no image will displayed.

**When I ispect I make this if image Displayed:**

```
<img ng-src="*path*/canvas_cnv1636941291475872489.jpg" alt=""
     class="btn-md custpro"
     onclick="RenewContract(this)" data-id="5"
     src="*path*/mh-images-local/canvas_cnv1636941291475872489.jpg">`
```

and when no image displayed url is:

```
<img ng-src="*Url*/" alt="" class="btn-md custpro"
     onclick="RenewContract(this)" data-id="6" src="*Url*/">
```

Comment: I am writing in controller : ProfilePic = baseUrlForStorage + t.ProfilePic

Answer (score 1):

you can use `ng-if`

incase the profile picture does not exist then:-

```
<img ng-if="rec.ProfilePic == null" ng-src="{{'~/img/UserDefault.png'}}"
     class="img-thumbnail img-fluid"
     style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:20px"
     alt="profile photo" />
```

incase the profile picture exists then:-

```
<img ng-if="rec.ProfilePic != null" ng-src="{{ rec.ProfilePic }}"
     class="img-thumbnail img-fluid"
     style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:20px"
     alt="profile photo" />
```

Comment: does AngularJS support *ngIf ?

Comment: @ManishBalodia edited my answer, the use of `onclick` instead of `ng-click` confused me

Comment: https://{NAME OF THE FOLDER}.blob.core.windows.net/[FOLDER]/[**NAME OF IMAGE**]   , **If NAME OF IMAGE is not present then how can I put Default Image**

Comment: @pri look at the two `<img>` tags in my answer, just write both of those tags in your code and because of the `ng-if` only one tag will be rendered

Comment: I am writing in controller : ProfilePic = baseUrlForStorage + t.ProfilePic

Comment: @pri share your code in a fiddle, I will fix it for you

Answer (score 1):

Either use this

```
 <img ng-src="{{ imageUrl == null ? defaultImageUrl : imageUrl }}" >
```

or

```
 <img ng-src="{{ ! imageUrl ? defaultImageUrl : imageUrl }}" >
```

you are trying to compare `null` == `'null'`

Comment: https://{NAME OF THE FOLDER}.blob.core.windows.net/[FOLDER]/[**NAME OF IMAGE**]   , **If NAME OF IMAGE is not present then how can I put Default Image**

Comment: I am writing in controller : ProfilePic = baseUrlForStorage + t.ProfilePic

Comment: Are you telling  like  t.ProfilePic is Null or not present if so , you can use the ternary operator in controller like this   baseUrlForStorage + ( t.profilePic ?  t.profilePic : defaultImageName ) , by doing so you can directly use the ProfilePic value in ng-src

Answer (score 1):

The ternary can be replaced with a [logical operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

```
̶<̶i̶m̶g̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶s̶r̶c̶=̶"̶{̶{̶r̶e̶c̶.̶P̶r̶o̶f̶i̶l̶e̶P̶i̶c̶=̶=̶'̶n̶u̶l̶l̶'̶ ̶?̶ ̶'̶~̶/̶i̶m̶g̶/̶U̶s̶e̶r̶D̶e̶f̶a̶u̶l̶t̶.̶p̶n̶g̶'̶ ̶:̶'̶{̶{̶r̶e̶c̶.̶P̶r̶o̶f̶i̶l̶e̶P̶i̶c̶'̶}̶}̶"̶
<img ng-src="{{rec.ProfilePic || '~/img/UserDefault.png'}}"
     class="img-thumbnail img-fluid"
     style="border: 1px solid #ddd;margin-bottom:20px"
     alt="profile photo" />
```

The `&&` and `||` operators actually return the value of one of the specified operands, so if these operators are used with non-Boolean values, they will return a non-Boolean value.

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: https://{NAME OF THE FOLDER}.blob.core.windows.net/[FOLDER]/[**NAME OF IMAGE**]   , **If NAME OF IMAGE is not present then how can I put Default Image**

Comment: I am writing in controller :  ProfilePic = baseUrlForStorage + t.ProfilePic,